# Android Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am getting this error when i try to build my game for android.

**What I've tried**

- I have looked at all the other answers on Stack Overflow but nothing seems to work
- I have deleted the 24.0.0 Build tools
- I have tried different jdk

I always get the same error trying to build for android.

I am using **Unity 5.3.8** and **Mac Yosemite**

**Error details**

> CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. See the
>   Console for
>   details./Users/admin/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/android-4.4W/aapt
>   package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S
>   "res" -I
>   "/Users/admin/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-26/android.jar" -F
>   bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages
>   com.google.unity:android.support.v7.appcompat:com.facebook.android:com.google.android.gms:com.google.android.gms.ads.impl:com.google.android.gms.ads:com.google.android.gms.base:com.google.android.gms:com.google.android.gms.clearcut:com.google.android.gms.gass:com.google.android.gms.tasks:android.support.v4
>   -S "/Users/admin/Desktop/game/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-23.1.1/res"
>   -S "/Users/admin/Desktop/game/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/facebook/res"
>   -S "/Users/admin/Desktop/game/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/google-play-services_lib/res"
>   -S "/Users/admin/Desktop/game/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/play-services-ads-10.0.1/res"
>   -S "/Users/admin/Desktop/game/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/play-services-ads-lite-10.0.1/res"
>   -S "/Users/admin/Desktop/game/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/play-services-base-10.0.1/res"
>   -S "/Users/admin/Desktop/game/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/play-services-basement-10.0.1/res"
>   -S "/Users/admin/Desktop/game/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/play-services-clearcut-10.0.1/res"
>   -S "/Users/admin/Desktop/game/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/play-services-gass-10.0.1/res"
>   -S "/Users/admin/Desktop/game/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/play-services-tasks-10.0.1/res"
>   -S "/Users/admin/Desktop/game/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/support-v4-24.0.0/res"stderr[/Users/admin/Desktop/game/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/google-play-services_lib/res/values/admob_ads_attrs.xml:10: error: Attribute "adSize" has already been
>   defined/Users/admin/Desktop/game/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/google-play-services_lib/res/values/admob_ads_attrs.xml:17: error: Attribute "adSizes" has already been
>   defined/Users/admin/Desktop/game/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/google-play-services_lib/res/values/admob_ads_attrs.xml:20: error: Attribute "adUnitId" has already been
>   defined/Users/admin/Desktop/game/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-23.1.1/res/values/values.xml:110:
>   error: Attribute "theme" has already been
>   defined]stdout[Configurations

Comment: Have you been able to fix this issue ? If yes, please share the solution as I am having the same issue. Thanks.